# Importing global variables between modules

Tags: python, string, variables, module

The current set up for my python code is as follows:

Also used for other projects:
general_settings.py - taking care of the imports and some general utility functions 
actual_functions.py - the 'workhorse functions' for the project

Project specific
variable_names.py = this is where strings are declared into variables
run_project.py - this is where I am calling the functions

I am using information from excel spreadsheets which are read into Pandas Dataframes. 
Because for each project the source excel spreadsheets can be different, I am using a variable name for the columns in the code.

For example if I want to sum the balance of a column, instead of doing

`df['Balance'].sum()`

I would first define balance:

`bal = 'Balance'  and then use df[bal].sum()`

The reason is that sometimes the of the source excel files have a different header, for example 'Current Balance' instead of Balance.
By updating the variable 'bal' I can therefore easily account for this, it also allows me to use short variable names, keeping the code short, and use autocomplete (I am using PyCharm).

In actual_functions.py and run_project.py I use the statement from general_settings `import * and from variable_names import *`

This works fine, but doesn't feel like the optimal solution.
1. In case I want to use actual_functions.py to run a different tape, I have to change the import statement at the top of this script.
2. I am using global variables to pass through strings, which doesn't feel like good practice

The two points above can be solved by using parameters in the functions where these variables are defined, however because there are quite a few on variable names (around 20), it is not workable to import each of the variable names in functions in actual_functions.py.

Is it possible some sort of settings file (dictionary) to import the variable names / strings into each of the functions? Or a different solution which I am missing? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks for the answer below, I found this reference for using subclasses http://devanla.com/case-for-inheriting-from-pandas-dataframe.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single function that requires a lot of parameters then you can help by providing helpful defaults so that when called only some of the parameters need to be supplied.

If you have a set of related functions that take a similar set of parameters then consider putting them in a class and make the common settings member variables.